# cost effective way of showing a maintenance page in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, failover

Situation: you have an ec2 that you don't want to have running all the time to save costs. A use case for that could be an EC2 used for infrequent video-conferencing.
When it's offline, I want to display a page that it's currently offline, instead of visitors not be able to resolve the domain name.

Using load-balancers is pretty costly as you pay for every hour they don't run. In the example above: if you use the video conferencing only 1 or 2 times per month, then having an Application Load Balancer running the entire time, already costs you more than $20,- per month (around $250,- per year).
So that is not an option.

I've tried to create a failover to an S3 bucket using health checks and Route53 (as explained here for example: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/fail-over-s3-r53/), but this is not a good solution because of browser cache. Even with the TTL of the DNS record set to 60 seconds, it can take hours before a browser decides to do a new lookup. This means that if a user visits just before the server comes online, they will not be able to reach it at a later moment if they use the refresh button.

Btw, this setup uses a domain name, an elastic IP and an ssl certificate for https.

What is the most cost effective way to tackle this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could redirect users to another html page by using cloudfront and lambda@edge. Lambda@edge could read maintenance window from a db (Dynamodb) and redirect to maintenance page depending on the request time window.

Comment: A redirect is not really a good solution imo, because the url should be static and either serve the functionality the EC2 is providing or a maintenance page when it's offline. If you _redirect_ a user to a maintenance page, then they're stuck on a static maintenance page. Or am I misinterpreting what you're suggesting?
Also, I prefer not to use anything time based. It should simply failover when the ec2 is not available. That way it also works when it's offline due to problems

Comment: Here's one solution: use API Gateway as your endpoint, invoking a Lambda to check on the status of the live server. If it's down, the Lambda sends a redirect to the static content page; if up, it sends a redirect to the actual server (and you'll need a redirect, because unless you use an Elastic IP you'll get a different public IP address each time you start the server).

Comment: To let the Lambda know when the actual server is live, you can use a DynamoDB table that's updated when the server starts up or shuts down. The only issue with this is that you need to guarantee that you update the table when the server is down, although you could use a TTL on the entry to auto-delete (or a timestamp to let the Lambda decide whether the record is valid).

Comment: That's not an answer, however, because I don;t believe that it's a _good_ solution. I would instead use an always-on `t4g.micro` instance, which will cost you roughly $6/month. The video conferencing software shouldn't require excessive CPU (unless it's doing local rendering), and the `t4g` has decent network bandwidth.

Comment: Your biggest expense, however, is likely to be data transfer at $0.09/GB out from EC2. Video uses a _lot_ of bandwidth, and I _strongly_ recommend testing your solution lest you get an unpleasant surprise in your AWS bill.

Comment: @kdgregory : I need a c5.xlarge, because it's a requirement for using BigBlueButton, which costs 145,- per month. Which is why I want to take it offline when it's not used, because then it will be just a few dollars :-) The setup also has an elastic ip and ssl certificates.